# Is it possible to consume conan package's binaries outside of conan cache?

Tags: c++, conan

Let's say I have two projects. Lib and App.
App has Lib in it's `conanfile.txt`. Normally when `conan install` of App's dependencies is performed conan downloads and compiles Lib to `~/.conan/data/`.
Is it possible to link App to Lib that is currently being worked on instead (e.g. `/home/path/to/code/Lib/cmake-build-release/lib/` )?

The reason I want to do this is to debug a Lib's bug whose only known way to reproduce is by using App. I want to be able to quickly add `std::cout` to certain places and incrementally recompile. Rebuilding the whole conan package and doing `conan install` each time is too long. I was thinking about some hack that would change include path and linking path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, Conan uses the same approach as Python `pip`: the "editable" packages. You can read more about it in this section of the docs: [Editable packages](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/developing_packages/editable_packages.html). The basic idea is:

- You `cd libfolder` and define it as a package in edition: `conan editable add lib/1.0`
- You can build the `lib` there, like `conan install .` + `cmake ..` or `conan build .`
- You can go to the App folder `cd appfolder` and do a `conan install .`. You should see that `lib/1.0` is marked as "editable" and not from the Conan cache. You can build `App`, and it will be linking your dependency to `lib` from the local `libfolder`.
- Every change that you do to `libfolder` and build there locally (incremental builds), will be directly available to `App` without needing to `create` or `export-pkg` to the Conan cache.

The editable feature relies on the correct definition in `lib/1.0` of the project layout, in its `layout()` method. There are built-in layouts like `cmake_layout(self)`.

If the different packages lib and app generate compatible projects, like Visual Studio, it is possible to join those projects in the IDE and have a convenient development and debugging experience of both packages together. There is a live demo in [this C++ Italian Meetup presentation](https://youtu.be/VzUJQw89U7o?t=2768)